# code can be progress but shown has error when i convert html in r

Tags: r

I would like to convert my r file to HTML, but it always turns this error even if my code is good to process.

```
error 
Quitting from lines 71-90 (HW1.Rmd) 
Error in eval(quote(list(...)), env) : object 'MAD' not found
Calls: <Anonymous> ... [.data.frame -> order -> standardGeneric -> eval -> eval -> eval
Execution halted
```

error part code

```
ss <- data.frame(
 MED = apply(exprs(ESET),1,median),
  MAD = apply(exprs(ESET),1,mad)
)
sort(ss$MAD, decreasing = TRUE)[1:101]
highlight_df <- ss %>% 
             filter(MAD>3.800260)
ss %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=MED,y=MAD)) + 
  geom_point(pch=20) +
  geom_point(data=highlight_df, 
             aes(x=MED,y=MAD,color = top100), 
             color='red',
             size=3)

top <- ss[order(-MAD,-MED),]
top[1:10,]
```

Comment: This line shouldn't work: `ss[order(-MAD,-MED),]` Are you sure you don't get an error all the time? With base R it should look like `top <- ss[order(-ss$MAD,-ss$MED),]`. But that doesn't have anything to do with making HTML output.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).